# Detect if is an AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, go

How can I detect, if a request is an AJAX or not?

Would checking

```
req.Header.Get("X-Requested-With")
```

work for all browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately "X-Requested-With" is not always reliable.  If you are in control of making the Ajax call you may use the beforeSend function to ensure this is set:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/url",
    data: { signature: authHeader },
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'xmlhttprequest');},
    success: function() { alert('Success!' + authHeader); }
});
```

You may then check if `req.Header.Get("X-Requested-With") == 'xmlhttprequest'`